# ASP.net out of memory help

Tags: asp.net, memory-management

My first question here :)

I have a report generating website. When the user clicks a button the report is generated in a different sub as a html-file and is written to a txt-file. The html-file is later converted to a PDF in a different sub.

When the report is long (200 pages), I get out of memory exception when the PDF is generated. Memory seams to be allocated by the html generation, since when I convert the html to PDF in a different webform it works perfect.

I have tried to use analysis program like ANTS, but I dont have the knowledge to sort it out.

How can I release the html generation from memory?

Thanks!
/Georg

Answer (score 0):

Your memory from a good component should hopefully get cleared out - however in this case since its a fairly large document it may by OK design but max the memory out. You can 
1. Try to increase the memory in IIS available to your worker process
2. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/911716
3. (you didnt specify server version so this is dependent on that) http://support.microsoft.com/kb/820108

With ANTS - there are tutorials on RedGates site discussing its usage. If its a third party component there may not be much you can do except increase the available memory or contact the vendor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will try ti increase the memory. But is their not a way to free the memory from the report generation? I dont need that info anymore since the report is stored on the server?